# Difference b/w @entity and @Component

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

What is the difference b/w the annotation `@Entity` and `@Component`?

I want to know what are the specific use cases and how we are going to use them in real time application

Comment: [Entity](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/persistence/Entity.html) and [Component](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Component.html)

Answer (score 0):

It's worth looking at the documentation which will explain quite a lot, but in a nutshell:

An `@Entity` is a persistence concept - eg. an instance of an entity may represent a row in your database.

A `@Component` is a class that is eligible to be scanned by Spring's auto-detection for dependency injection.